# Troubles with opencart moving

Tags: opencart

I constructed my opencart shop on localhost, then i tried to move it on my public host.
I created new DB on my server, i imported the DB from my computer to my server. I copied all my opencart site from computer to web hosting. I corrected both config.php files. 
Everything seemed be good, but i can'y access the most important part, 
admin panel - settings - edit shop 
it gives me this message:

Notice: Error: Unknown column 'name' in 'order clause'
Error No: 1054
SELECT * FROM customer_group ORDER BY name ASC in /homepages/32/d367271145/htdocs/opencart/system/database/mysql.php on line 49

somebody has the idea what am i doing wrong?

thankx 
marekova@alumni.uv.es

Answer (score 0):

Check your database and ensure you have entries under 'name' in customer_group.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've tried to use a database with the wrong version. Be sure your opencart versions are identical.

If they are, then the only possible way it would work on one and not the other is if like cleverbot has said, the database table doesn't contain the "name" column. You can check that in phpMyAdmin or whatever other DB admin tool you used to upload the database. The simplest solution would be to simply export customer_group from your localhost and re-import it into your live version